# MDX : calculate maximum value per dimension member

Tags: max, average, mdx

Good morning. i have the following fact table

```
FK_Cmd |FK_Ship |Dilevry_time
C001   |1       |20
C001   |2       |25
C002   |1       |23
```

i want to calculate the average maximum delivry time per Cmd which would be (25+23)/2 = 24 in the exemple. 
i am using the following MDX request :

```
AVG(MAX([Dim Cmd].[PR_Cmd],[Measures].[Delivery time]))
```

but i don't get any correct result. can you help with this ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would need to define it as a member something like:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Max Delivery time] AS Max   
   ([Dim Cmd].[PR_Cmd].currentMember  
      , [Measures].Delivery time]  
   )  

 MEMBER [Measures].[Avg Max Delivery time] AS Avg
   ([Dim Cmd].[PR_Cmd].allMembers
      , [Measures].[Max Delivery time]  
   ) 

SELECT [Measures].[Avg Max Delivery time] ON 0 
FROM [Cube]
```

I don't have SSAS currently so I cannot test it but it should be something similar. Another way would be to define it as calculated member in your cube definition if that's important metric for you instead of using MDX every time. It would be faster in the end because the cube will have that value ready for you.